# localStorage does not work when the input type is file; how can I save a file between routes in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

I am creating a React app that allows the user to upload a .csv file. The file contains data to be analyzed in the back end after the user presses the "Estimate network" button. I am able to upload a file, but it disappears after refreshing the page. The code I provide below, which I have found online, manages to retain the input using localStorage, as long as the input type is not a file. Other posts have clarified that this is because HTML does not allow the input value to be set for files, due to security reasons. Solutions have been provided using "blobs" but I am inexperienced and cannot understand what this means, let alone implement it. So, my question is: How can I retain files after refreshing the page / routing to a different component in React, when the input type is a file?

```
import React from 'react';
import '../App.css';
 
function Analyze () {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(
        localStorage.getItem('myValueInLocalStorage') || ''
  );
 
    React.useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('myValueInLocalStorage', value);
    }, [value]);
 
    const onChange = event => setValue(event.target.value);
 
    return (
        <div>
            <input 
            className="input" 
            onChange={onChange}
            type="file" 
            value={value}/>
            <button className="button">Estimate network</button>    
        </div>
        );
    }

export default Analyze
```

Comment: Have you considered using indexDB or saving the file as base64 encoded string in the local store

Comment: @MauriceA. I have tried saving as base64 but it did not work. I have not tried indexedDB.